# Increase summary length using MS Azure-AI services

Tags: azure-language-understanding, summarization, azure-ai

Recently, I have been using Azure AI cognitive services to summarize text using document summarization and conversation summarization of it. But the summary length using both document summarization and conversation summarization is very less.

Comment: What is the length you want? Are you using sdk or in portal?

Comment: maximum length you can give is 20

Comment: i am using SDK for this. in a way to move forward with summary generation, chunking would be a necessity. what are your suggestions on a conversation summary? i used conversational api too. the addition of data in that is a bit tedious in it for 'narrative' aspect.

Comment: Yeah I have provided the solution. kindly check it

Comment: yeah. i saw it. seems pretty accurate. thanks again.

Comment: if i were to implement same using conversational understanding available in LUIS. what is the parameter to be fine-tuned?

Comment: also, is this max_sentence_count applicable for abstractive summary?

Comment: I guess yes. There is parameter you can pass `sentenceCount` for abstractive summary.

Comment: where in the documentation did you find these parameters? I have been looking into them for sometime and couldn't find it. also, do you have any suggestions on data input for conversational summary using Azure AI?

Comment: refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/language/conversation-analysis-runtime/submit-job?view=rest-language-2023-04-01&tabs=HTTP#conversationsummarizationtaskparameters
you need to provide json and in  parameter section you need to give

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/language-service/summarization/quickstart?tabs=conversation-summarization%2Cwindows&pivots=programming-language-python#code-example

Comment: supposedly, the conversation is too long, then how should one proceed to add json data input. currently, it works well for small datasets. what should be done when we need to add long conversations? additionally, is it mandatory to add the 'role' and 'participantId'?

Comment: You need to load the conversation into json file or download it as json file and read it as json, then pass them. At the end you need give json data as input to analysis.

Comment: It depends on from where you are getting conversation data.

Comment: how should i go for the conversational summary? the question is in the provided link:https://stackoverflow.com/q/78045287/23453315

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/language-service/summarization/how-to/document-summarization#try-document-extractive-summarization), you can give a maximum sentence length of 20 for a summary.

If you want to get a summary with more than 20 sentences, you can split your document and summarize it.

Example: If your document length is long, split it based on the topic or according to your requirements, then summarize it.

Below is the document I have with a length of `4779`.

[image]

Next, split it and summarize it.

Here, I am using the Python SDK to perform an extractive summary.

Code:

```py
# This example requires environment variables named "LANGUAGE_KEY" and "LANGUAGE_ENDPOINT"
key = "db2............."
endpoint = "https://<congnitive_name>.cognitiveservices.azure.com/"

from azure.ai.textanalytics import TextAnalyticsClient
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential

# Authenticate the client using your key and endpoint 
def authenticate_client():
    ta_credential = AzureKeyCredential(key)
    text_analytics_client = TextAnalyticsClient(
            endpoint=endpoint, 
            credential=ta_credential)
    return text_analytics_client

client = authenticate_client()

# Example method for summarizing text
def sample_extractive_summarization(client,doc):

    poller1 = client.begin_extract_summary(documents=doc,max_sentence_count=20)

    document_results = poller1.result()
    for i in document_results:
        print(len(i['sentences']))




sample_extractive_summarization(client,document)
```

**Output** before chunking the document.

[image]

You can see a maximum of 20 sentences.

**Output** After chunking.

Code for chunking.

```py
def chunk_string(string, chunk_size):
    chunks = []
    for i in range(0, len(string), chunk_size):
        chunks.append(string[i:i+chunk_size])
    return chunks

chunk_size = 1000
chunks = chunk_string(document[0], chunk_size)

sample_extractive_summarization(client,chunks)
```

Here, I am chunking with a length of 1000.

[image]

Now, if you add those lengths, you will get `25` sentences.

With the help of chunking, you can increase the summary length.

**Note**: I just used indexing for chunking, but in your case, you should do chunking that makes sense for your document, like topic-wise splitting the document.