# conversational summary API of Azure AI services

Tags: azure

I am facing the below error in my code when running the conversational summary of Azure AI services. [Code error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ULf9.png). Can someone let me know where am i going wrong in the below code? The 'json_objects_output' are in the required form as per the documentation.

```
# analyze query
client = ConversationAnalysisClient(endpoint, AzureKeyCredential(key))
with client:
    poller = client.begin_conversation_analysis(
        task={
            "displayName": "Analyze conversations from xxx",
            "analysisInput": {
                "conversations": [
                    {
                    "conversationItems": json_objects_output,
                    "modality": "text",
                    "id": "conversation1",
                    "language": "en"
                    },
                ]
            },
            "tasks": [
                {
                    "taskName": "Chapter title task",
                    "kind": "ConversationalSummarizationTask",
                    "parameters": {
                        "summaryAspects": ["chapterTitle"]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "taskName": "Narrative task",
                    "kind": "ConversationalSummarizationTask",
                    "parameters": {
                        "summaryAspects": ["narrative"]
                    }
                },
            ]
        }
    )
    # view result
    result = poller.result()
    task_results = result["tasks"]["items"]
    for task in task_results:
        print(f"\n{task['taskName']} status: {task['status']}")
        task_result = task["results"]
        if task_result["errors"]:
            print("... errors occurred ...")
            for error in task_result["errors"]:
                print(error)
        else:
            conversation_result = task_result["conversations"][0]
            if conversation_result["warnings"]:
                print("... view warnings ...")
                for warning in conversation_result["warnings"]:
                    print(warning)
            else:
                summaries = conversation_result["summaries"]
                print("... view task result ...")
                for summary in summaries:
                    print(f"{summary['aspect']}: {summary['text']}")
```

The text file was converted to the json format using the below code:

```
import json
def convert_to_json(transcript_text):
    lines = transcript_text.strip().split('\n')
    json_objects = []
    for i, line in enumerate(lines, start=1):
        json_obj = {
            "text": line.strip(),
            "modality": "text",
            "id": str(i),
            "role": "Speaker_1",
            "participantId": "Speaker_1"
        }
        json_objects.append(json_obj)
    return json_objects
# Read transcript from text file
with open('/content/input.txt', 'r') as file:
    transcript_text = file.read()
# Convert transcript to JSON format
json_objects_output=json.dumps(convert_to_json(transcript_text), indent=2)
print(json_objects_output)
# json dumps file
with open('/content/output.json','w') as json:
  json.write(json_objects_output)
```

Attached is the output:
[output of json_object_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2PVX.png)

Comment: sample input.txt:
[
  {
    "text": "Hi.",
    "modality": "text",
    "id": "1",
    "role": "Speaker_1",
    "participantId": "Speaker_1"
    },
    {
    "text": "Hello.",
    "modality": "text",
    "id": "2",
    "role": "Speaker_1",
    "participantId": "Speaker_1"
    },
    {
    "text": "Hi.",
    "modality": "text",
    "id": "3",
    "role": "Speaker_1",
    "participantId": "Speaker_1"
  }
]

Answer (score 0):

You no need to do `json.dumps()`, you can pass that json object directly.

Because the `conversationItems` accepts array of records of type `json`,
when you do json dumps it converts it to string which is not valid.

```py
import  json
print(type(json_objects_output))
print(type(json.dumps(json_objects_output,indent=2)))
```

[image]

So, give it directly with out doing dumps.

Output:

[image]

Comment: it worked fine. but now I have the API key issue which is a problem from the organization's side.

Comment: Okay. What is the error and have you discussed regarding this with your organization?

Comment: the error is somewhat like this: ServiceRequestError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7da4a3a14520>: Failed to resolve 'prj-name.cognitiveservices.azure.com' ([Errno -2] Name or service not known)

Comment: check you are giving correct endpoint or not?